# Use `tf.contrib.predictor` to predict on batches from `tf.estimator.export_savedmodel` for TF 1.13

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I found several examples to load my saved estimator, `my_estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir, export_input_fn)` model, as a predictor like so, `predictor = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(export_dir)`. This works great when my `tf.train.Example` has only one item. How can I make it work for a batch for TF 1.13?

```py
model_input= tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'browser_name': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[b"chrome", b"ie"])),
      'version': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[8.0, 11.0]))     
  })).SerializeToString()
```

```py
predictor({"inputs":[model_input]})
```

call fails when there are multiple inputs per feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example with tensorflow 1.13.1 :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


prod_export_dir = 'my_model_dir'
data =  pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

predictor = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(prod_export_dir)

model_input = {}
for k, v in predictor.feed_tensors.items():
    model_input[k] = np.array(data[k].tolist(), dtype=v.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)

prediction = predictor(model_input)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an equivalent for 2.x? I only find examples which require serializing each example to a string and pass to a `tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_PATH).signatures["predict"]` instance

Answer (score 0):

```py
predictor({"inputs":[model_input1, model_input2]})
```

works but that requires enumerating the data manually into multiple `tf.train.Example` instances